# Use of union in a command data structure

Tags: c++, design-patterns, command-pattern

I am working on a project in which we pass commands to lower layer from upper layer.

*1. **Handle Single command at a time***

we use following data structure.

```
struct Command{
     //Different command types==> SEND / CREATE_TRANSACTION etc.
     CommandType type;

     //Associated parameters with every command
     union{
         struct{
             string remote_ip;
             uint16_t remote_port;
         }address;

         struct{
             string transaction_id;
             string transaction_details;
         }tsx;
         .
         .
         .
     }params;
};
```

We pass different parameters for different commands. Union makes it memory efficient.

**Is there any better way (or a design pattern) to do it in C++?**

Another one.

*2. **Handle multiple commands in a single command object.***

I can do it in this way:

```
struct Command{
    uint64_t flag; //ORed value of different command types 

    //parameters
    struct{
        string remote_ip;
        uint16_t remote_port;
    }address;

    struct{
        string transaction_id;
        string transaction details;
    }tsx;
};
```

But, it is not memory efficient.

**Is there any better way to create  multiple commands in a single object (in C++)?**

Answer (score 1):

You want [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant.html). Variants are type-safe discriminated unions.

```
struct address {
    string remote_ip;
    uint16_t remote_port;
};

struct tsx {
    string transaction_id;
    string transaction details;
};

using command = std::variant<address, tsx>;
```

Example usage:

```
command c0{tsx{/* ... */}};
std::visit(
    overload(
        [](const address&){ /* handle address case */ },
        [](const tsx&)    { /* handle tsx case */ }
    ),
    c0
);
```

In order to learn how to implement `overload` and similar pattern-matching utilities, refer to my ACCU 2017 talk: ["Implementing variant Visitation Using Lambdas"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqei4JJRQ7s)

Comment: @Vittoria Thanks for suggestion about variant. It is only supported in C++17  and for earlier versions, perhaps there are third party implementations. For older versions, is there any other efficient way to do it, in std. c++??

Comment: @King: I suggest using `boost::variant`. It's production-ready

Answer (score -1):

You could use std::variant and a visitor pattern. Depending on the command type your visitor would react differently to process the payload data.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

This provides type safety that unions do not offer

Answer (score -1):

Using unions as "variants", particularly for the purpose of "saving memory", is almost always an indication of poor design. You need to question the if design/specification makes sense. So yes, there are much better ways:

If these 2 structs have nothing to do with each other, then keep them as 2 separate structs (or classes). Designing programs without tight coupling is vastly more important than saving 10-20 bytes of memory.

Otherwise, if these 2 structs do have something in common, make "params" an abstract base class that contains whatever the structs have in common. Then have "address" and "tsx" inherit that base class.